# How to Configure Server-Level Cache on Nginx with Certbot in the equation

Tags: nginx, caching, server, configuration, nginx-config

I'm building a website on wordpress, I'm trying to configure cache ***"without"*** a plugin, I tried to configure nginx to proxy cache but it didn't work, please check my .confs

First I needed to change my user.conf to start listening to another port
the problem is, when I changer listener, the website doesn't respond to new port, I believe certbot is overriding : (for example when I change listen 8000, website doesn't respond to https://example.com:8000)

```
upstream example-php-handler {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass example-php-handler;
        }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot          >>>  # When I change this port to :8000 website doesn't respond to https://example.com:8000
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

**and then I create a file for cache as: cache.conf:**

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=custom_cache:10m inactive=60m;
upstream origin_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;     # Do I need to change the ip to the Internal ip ? it's Ephemeral, should I change it to static and place it here?
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://origin_server;
        proxy_cache custom_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid any 10m;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}
```

**Also, as I noted in the cache.conf do I need to change the internal ip to static and replace the default (127.0.0.1) with a static one? or place the Ephemeral one? or keep default?**

I'm beginner at this, all help is appreciated, thanks.